# setInterval is preventing click handler from firing

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, setinterval

Here's an example of the code I have.  I load new content with 'setInterval'.  It's causing my click handler not to fire.

The ajax calls a file called 'content.php' which just contains this:

```
<a class='my_link'>Something here</a>
```

This is my page:

```
<div id="content">
<a class='my_link'>Something here</a>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.my_link').click(function() {
alert($(this).html()); 
return false;
});

function loadLog(){     
    var oldscrollHeight = $("#chatbox").attr("scrollHeight") - 20;
    $.ajax({
        url: "content.php",
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){        
            $("#content").html(html); //Insert chat log into the #chatbox div               
            var newscrollHeight = $("#chatbox").attr("scrollHeight") - 20;
            if(newscrollHeight > oldscrollHeight){
                $("#content").animate({ scrollTop: newscrollHeight }, 'normal'); //Autoscroll to bottom of div
            }               
        },
    });
};
setInterval (loadLog, 3000);
});
```

Comment: If loadLog is called, `$("#content").html(html);` will make your click handler on .my_link to no more works. Is it your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you add the link after the `$('.myLink').click(...` was already executed, it does not have the 'click' handler attached.

You will need to use a *delegate*:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.my_link', function(e){

    alert($(this).html()); 
    return false;

});
```

Read more about delegates in **[jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)**